# Can I get a reference to jsx react component so I can I forceUpdate/rerender react component from the chrome developer console?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, render, jsx

I have basic hello world react component rendering
inside my rails app.

I'm trying to make the component redraw, so that it picks up (via Ajax) some data changes that happened in the Postgres database.

From the chrome developer console, how can I get a "reference"
to the react component, so that I can call the .forceUpdate() method of the component?

My code:

```
// ideas from https://medium.com/@hpux/rails-5-1-loves-javascript-a1d84d5318b
// app/javascript/packs/hello_react.jsx 
import React from 'react'                                                                                    
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'                                                                             
class Hello extends React.Component {
  // stuff ...
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {                                                       
  ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="React" />, document.getElementById('my-div'))                       
})
```

What I tried

changing

```
ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="React" />, document.getElementById('my-div'))
```

to

```
var foo = ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="React" />, document.getElementById('my-div'))
```

Then in the developer console, I did

```
foo
```

I got

> Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
>       at :1:1 (anonymous) @ VM4867:1

Update:

I tried this in the chrome dev console

```
> ReactDOM
```

I got

```
VM4871:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM4871:1
```

Update: I found a hakish solution, hoping someone can offer better:

```
constructor() { super(); if ( window ) { window.myThing = this; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should install the [React Developer Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) extension for Chrome or Firefox. After restarting the browser, you can open the React tab and inspect your component. Then if you change to the console tab and type `$r.` you should see the methods of that component (you can access to the state, props and much more as well).

`$r.forceUpdate()`

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm not trying to call forceUpdate() for me to see, this web application is used by folks who don't have the react dev tools installed

Comment: to give more context: the react component should re-render itself when the customer adds a credit card and the stripe.js hook is executed

Comment: Have you check the [refs section from the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
import React from 'react'                                                                                    
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'                                                                             
class Hello extends React.Component {
  // stuff ...
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => { 
  const helloComponent = <Hello name="React" />;

  window.helloComponent = helloComponent;   <-----------------

  ReactDOM.render(helloComponent, document.getElementById('my-div'))                       
})
```

Then, access your components from the console as `helloComponent`